# Generating a text file in MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, text-files

I'm new to MySQL, I am trying to create a text file using a stored procedure.  I'm currently at the stage where I have a temporary table that contains all of the records that I want to output to a text file.  I have the following line at the end of my SP, it works in PHPMYAdmin's query but it does not work when part of a stored procedure the code is as follows:

SELECT * into outfile '../../htdocs/VIP/Temp/temp.txt' from tmp_Menu2;

note that tmp_Menu2 is a table that only includes one field of type VARCHAR(1000)

Any help would be greathly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The user making the call needs file privileges on the host. The text file will be created on the server.

Comment: The directory where I'm putting the information is on the server and the user is the root user which has all the permissions.  ???

Comment: The MySQL user. `GRANT FILE ON db_name.* TO 'mysql_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd'; flush privileges;` You shouldn't run mysql as root, BTW.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently just at the evaluation stage to determine if MYSql is functional enough to devellop my app on.  I'm trying to avoid running with Microsoft SQL eventhow I know that DB system very well.  MySQL appears to be faster and more flexible as to what platform I need to use so I would like it to work but so far I'm finding a lot of limitations that I don't like.